# center and scale input controls

Tags: html, css

Given [this page](http://mygolfscore-app.com/), how can I better center vertically and scale the 4 buttons to be 50% in width (to the browser's width) and 20% in height (to the browser's height) where the other 20% (the buttons would take up 80% because there are 4 of them) in height is evenly spaced between them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/dj2fu/

You need a couple of things to get it working the way you want.

Remove the `<br>`s

Apply the following CSS:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#divMainMenu {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#divMainMenu input[type="button"] {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
}​
```

Comment: When I place this into my page (at the bottom of the CSS part) the width and centering works perfect but the height doesn't for some reason. It's still normal height for the buttons. Are my other div tags that I have below this main one causing issues?

Comment: The thing is I hide and show these div tags so they sort of act like dialog windows. This must be applied while they are shown, and then on the javascript load is where I hide them. I guess though if this is applied dynamically with the browser window because of the % you'd think because the other div tags are hidden it would ignore them.

Comment: Actually it's working in chrome but not IE 10. Any ideas why?

Comment: Changing the `display: table` in `#divMainMenu` to `display: block` should be sufficient to make it work in IE

Comment: ty so much. Now I have to read up about how this is working. ty again so much!